# Android device access local host on laptop

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json

I am new to android and backend development and came in a problem today. I have setup rails server on my computer and localhost:3000 shows ruby page. My android device (connected by usb) main activity has a webview and I tried localhost:3000

Answer (score 5):

### Use Your IP Address Instead of Localhost

Instructions if you're on a Mac. Other OS's, do something comparable.

1. Connect your computer and Android tablet to the same Wifi connection.
2. Open **System Preferences**.
3. Go to the **Network** section.
4. Click on your Wifi connection and copy your IP address from that window:

   [image: Network Settings]
5. Make sure your Rails server is running on port 3000.
6. On your tablet, point to your computer IP address with port 3000,

   ```
   192.168.0.14:3000
   ```

   [image: Navigate on your tablet]

Hope that helps!

/ JP

Answer (score 3):

- Just simple, you should try to do these steps same as  below:
- First, you type this command in order to show your ip address: `ifconfig`
- Second, in your console, type this command: `rails s -b your_ip_address`

  - For example: `rails s -b 192.168.1.102`
- Finally, open browser on your android and type: `192.168.1.102:3000`

You can read this rails official to understand clearly.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#default-host-for-rails-server

Answer (score 0):

http://smyck.net/2007/03/11/how-to-bind-webrick-to-any-ip-address/

You need to bind your webrick to ip address of your ethernet or wifi adapter.

Answer (score 0):

if your laptop and device are on the same wifi, just connect to the hostname or IP of your laptop http://[laptop Ip or hostname]:3000